# How would I interpret time in an if/else PHP statement?

Tags: php, codeigniter, if-statement, time

```
$currentTime = date("Hi");

if($currentTime > 0559 && $currentTime < 1401) {
     // Stuff here
}
```

That's my current code, but the if statement seems to be running any time after midnight, not just after 0600 (6:00 AM local time). Any ideas what would be causing this.

Comment: If you start a integer literal with a `0`, it's interpreted as octal.

Comment: but since date() returns a string, you can use $currentTime > '0559' and it should work...

Comment: Funny thing is that `0559` is actually equal to `45`: `9` gets thrown off, as this digit obviously can't be used in octadecimals. So, to be precise, the script works at any time past `00:45`, not `any time after midnight`. )

Answer (score 3):

In `(if($currentTime > 0559)` - `0559` will be considered as `octal` because of the preceeding `0`.

Simply remove that in the comparison `if($currentTime > 559)`

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you! I knew it was going to be something silly like this.

Answer (score 2):

You are using an integer in another way of what you think you are using, please check `integer` documentation [**here**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)

**example**

```
$a = 0123; // octal number (equivalent to 83 decimal)
```

Let's get back to your code, to fix it just remove that `0` before your integer so it won't be interpreted as `octal`, just change to

```
if(($currentTime > 559) && ($currentTime < 1401)) {
    // Stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using Integers.

```
$currentTime = intval( date("Hi") );

if ($currentTime > 559 && $currentTime < 1401) {
    // Stuff here
}
```